# Change bullet type for each level of Outline Environment

Tags: lists, itemize

I love using the `outline` environment (`outlines` package) for taking notes in class. `\1` uses a standard bullet, `\2` uses a dash. I wanted to make `\3` a bullet and `\4` a dash as well. How would I go about doing this as I'm fairly new to LaTeX.

Comment: Can you please create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)? It really helps us, but in the end you as well.

Comment: I'm just using the package "outlines". Then I can go start{outline} and use \1, \2, \3, or \4 for 4 levels of indentation. So my main points are at a \1 while sub points are a \2 and so on. The default "bullet" for \3 is a * and I want to change that for the whole document. Currently I am going \3[$\bullet$] for each level three to change the bullet type.

Comment: If the answer solves your problem, please consider accepting it. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)

Answer (score 4):

The `outline` environment (in its default form) behaves as `itemize`, so you can modify `\labelitemiii` and `\labelitemiv`:

```
\renewcommand{\labelitemiii}{\textbullet}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiv}{\textendash}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{outlines}

\renewcommand{\labelitemiii}{\textbullet}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiv}{\textendash}

\begin{document}
\begin{outline}
   \1 Level 1
      \2 Level 2
         \3 Level 3
            \4 Level 4
\end{outline}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Can I make it work on beamer as well?